# Meaningful Method Name

Tags: methods, filenames

I'm writing a method which calculates a user's phone recharge credit expires within n months.
I couldn't think of a meaningful name. At the moment, it is called getCreditExpiresInNMths();
What would you name it?

Hope you don't think it is a silly question, I think a good method name is important. :)

Sarah

Comment: Wait, what's it supposed to do? I don't understand your explanation.

Comment: Sorry :P  
Let me try again, the method is to calculate the number of months until credits expire.  (borrowed words from duffymo).
I think I confused duffymo as well. Sorry guys. 
I think I can call it calculateNumberOfMonthUtilCreditExpiration();
Guess it's more of my English language incompetence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
public Money calculatePhoneRechargeCredits(int numMonthsUntilExpiration);
```

Comment: Yes, the parameter name is almost as important as the method name, in this case.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I got it. 
Sorry I didn't explain the problem well.